# Why does excel tables break VLOOKUP formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a worksheet using raw data that Excel does not identify as Tables (ie. plainly putting values in adjacent cells), and on another part of my worksheet, formulas doing lookup in that data, like

```
VLOOKUP(D$1, Config!$C$4:$E$8,2,FALSE)
```

Things are going perfectly well, until I decide to declare my raw data as a table (Ctrl-T) to get some extra functionality, like auto-formatting and auto table expansion.

Once the table declared, all my formulas find #N/A in that table, whether I reference the search zone as cell reference (`Config!$C$4:$E$8`) or by its new table name (modified via the name manager).

**A clue** (I don't know what it's worth) is that the lookup key (`D$1` in my formula) and the data keys (leftmost column of `Config!$C$4:$E$8`) are numeric (values like `2015`). Excel seems to use text lookup when inside a table and fail to match `2015` (in the table) with `"2015"` (from `D$1`). This is only a clue, I may be wrong on this.

What can I do to start using tables (auto expanding is really useful) without breaking my fomulas?

**EDIT :** Things break when the lookup key (`D$1`) starts being part of a table: 2015 is now seen by formulas as "2015"

Comment: A dirty workaround would be of course to not include `D$1` into a table: as it is the table header, I could declare to Excel that my table has no header, thus keeping the first line untouched.

Comment: To test your clue try to substitute the `D$1` with a `D$1 & ""` or a `D$1 + 0` if neither is giving results, the issue lies with something else.

Answer (score 0):

As sicarius92 points out in his comment, dealing with the changed data type by 'casting' it with `D$1 + 0` works for me.

Still, it's only a workaround and doesn't explain why putting data in tables magically change the data type.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2010 (don't know for sure how it used to work in 2007), transforming a range into a table turns the headers contents into text, independently of the contents. If you really want to have numbers in the headers, you have to mark the cells formatting as "Number" or "General" (or whatever you need) and reinsert the former data, as apparently Excel also disables the check for incompatible data types (and the automatic solution, the little green arrow and its menu).

Answer (score 0):

Laws-a-mercy guys...

A simple `IFERROR()` solves this problem. Given that you know a lookup value MIGHT be numeric in the lookup table but NOT numeric in the lookup value cell, just do:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D$1,Config!$C$4:$E$8,2,FALSE),  VLOOKUP(VALUE(D$1),Config!$C$4:$E$8,2,FALSE))
```

The above is just to generalize the formula. If you care not copying it elsewhere, then you KNOW the lookup value is a number being treated as text and you only need the "failure" half of the formula. If you don't know for sure, or you don't know AT ALL, but want to proof it against this kind of problem, use the whole thing.

It works the other way around as well. Say you have a numeric lookup value (as in, Excel thinks it is numeric {where here, Excel thinks the lookup value is text}). Just use `TEXT()` instead of `VALUE()` to solve it:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D$1,Config!$C$4:$E$8,2,FALSE),  VLOOKUP(TEXT(D$1,"@"),Config!$C$4:$E$8,2,FALSE))
```

(And if neither solves it, you have the nightmare of looking for garbage characters in one place or the other... Since headers aren't usually data sourced outside one's safe, controlled world, try the lookup range material first. Unless one imported headers to wherever the headers are (you know, like imported the whole material the lookup value comes from). Or if you imported both sets of data.)